# Unclear usage of any_vars and all_vars predicates when filtering rows over multiples columns using negative str_detect

Tags: r, dplyr

I am building a network :

```
from <- c("America, port unspecified", "Boston", "Chicago", "America, port unspecified")
to <-  c("Europe, port unspecified", "Nantes", "Le Havre", "Lisbonn")

dataset <- data.frame(from, to)

library(dplyr)
```

I want to subset my datatset with  rows NOT containing unspecified ports :

```
     from       to
     Boston     Nantes
     Chicago    Le Havre
```

I tried this : in the code below I’m searching for the string “port unspecified” across all columns. I want to keep rows where the string “port unspecified” is NOT present in ANY of the variables.

```
dataset2 <- dataset %>%
              filter_all(any_vars(!str_detect(., "port unspecified")))
```

Result :

```
 from   to
Boston  Nantes
Chicago Le Havre
America, port unspecified   Lisbonn
```

I tried the code below  with sucess :

```
dataset3 <- dataset %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(!str_detect(., "port unspecified")))
```

Result :

```
from  to
Boston  Nantes
Chicago Le Havre
```

Why all_vars gives me the expected result and not any_vars ?

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer if it worked otherwise clarify what you are looking for. Also same for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410374/transmute-over-all-columns-removing-comma-and-every-characters-after-comma

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% filter_all(any_vars(!str_detect(., "port unspecified")))
```

This reads as select rows where `"port unspecified"` is absent in **`any`** of the column which is row 2, 3, 4.

whereas this

```
dataset %>% filter_all(all_vars(!str_detect(., "port unspecified")))
```

means select rows where `"port unspecified"`  is absent in **`all`** of the columns which is row 2 and 3.

Hope this is clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using base `R` you can get the equivalent result as well:

```r
from <- c("America, port unspecified", "Boston", "Chicago", "America, port unspecified")
to <-  c("Europe, port unspecified", "Nantes", "Le Havre", "Lisbonn")

dataset <- data.frame(from, to)

# Loop through each column cand check for any port unspecified
semi <- lapply(dataset, grepl, pattern = "port unspecified")

# check which rows have a port unspecified (`pmax`) and exclude them with `!`.
dataset[!do.call(pmax, semi), ]
#>      from       to
#> 2  Boston   Nantes
#> 3 Chicago Le Havre
```