# transmute over all columns : removing comma and every characters after comma

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to remove commas and every characters after commas in strings over all columns

```
from <- c("UK, port unspecified", "Nantes", "London", "America", "La Martinique, port unspecified")
to <- c("Benin", "Widha", "France, *", "America, Port unspecified", "London")

network <- data.frame(from, to)
```

My df :

```
                              from                        to
 1            UK, port unspecified                     Benin
 2                          Nantes                     Widha
 3                          London                 France, *
 4                         America America, Port unspecified
 5 La Martinique, port unspecified                    London
```

What I want :

```
                              from                        to
 1                               UK                    Benin
 2                          Nantes                     Widha
 3                          London                    France
 4                         America                   America
 5                    La Martinique                    London
```

Can I combine `transmute_all` (or `transmute_if`) (package dplyr) and `split` (package tidyr) functions in dplyr pipe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate_all`/`transmute_all` and remove everything after comma using `sub`.

```
library(dplyr)
network  %>%  mutate_all(~sub(",.*", "", .))

#           from      to
#1            UK   Benin
#2        Nantes   Widha
#3        London  France
#4       America America
#5 La Martinique  London
```

Or in base R with `lapply`.

```
df[] <- lapply(network, function(x) sub(",.*", "", x))
```

**data**

Reading data as characters by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
network <- data.frame(from, to, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Why not using transmute_all ?

Comment: @Wilcar In this case, you can use both `mutate_all` as well as `transmute_all`.

Comment: sub is a grep function ? so I can also you str_extract ?

Comment: `sub` and `grep` are different functions. Yes, you can also use `str_extract` however, I think using `sub` seems straightforward to me. Maybe `str_remove` ? `network %>% transmute_all(~str_remove(., ",.*"))`